# if not statement with OR condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to display an invalid message if the input is not A,B or C. However the Or condition does not work properly

```
  var1 = (input("Enter type (A, B, C):  "))
    if not  var1 == 'A' or 'B' or 'C' : 
        print('Invalid entry')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Comment: Or is working properly. That expression is equivalent to ((not var1) == 'A') or 'B' or 'C'. What you want to do is expressed with var1 not in {'A', 'B', 'C'}